# Restrict Files from sudo User

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, sudo

*(Developer here - relative novice in the sysadmin world).*

Does anyone know of a way that files can be restricted (no read, write, or execute access) from the sudo user?

A little background on the situation:
We're currently searching for a way to provide sudo access to some users while still restricting access to a set of files. Unless this is accomplished, sudo access will not be an option, and we will instead whitelist files/commands (or wrap them in a script) as necessary in response to user requests.

As you might expect, the whitelist option would require a great deal more upkeep and delay as users wait for the sysadmin team to respond to requests.

Answer (score 5):

The way I usually implement this kind of restrictions requires that several conditions are met, otherwise the restrictions can be easily circumvented:

- The user does not belong to the `wheel` group, the only one authorized to use `su` (enforced via PAM).
- The user is given a **properly secured** `rbash` with a read-only `PATH` pointing to a private `~/bin`, this `~/bin/` directory contains links to simple utilities:

  ```
  $ ll ~/bin
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 14 Sep 17 08:58 clear -> /usr/bin/clear*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  7 Sep 17 08:58 df -> /bin/df*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 egrep -> /bin/egrep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  8 Sep 17 08:58 env -> /bin/env*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 fgrep -> /bin/fgrep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud  9 Sep 17 08:58 grep -> /bin/grep*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 10 Sep 17 08:58 rview -> /bin/rview*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 rvim -> /usr/bin/rvim*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 sudo -> /usr/bin/sudo*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 17 Sep 17 08:58 sudoedit -> /usr/bin/sudoedit*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 13 Sep 17 08:58 tail -> /usr/bin/tail*
  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root dawud 11 Sep 17 08:58 wc -> /usr/bin/wc*
  ```
- the user is given a restricted, read-only environment (think of stuff like `LESSSECURE`, `TMOUT`, `HISTFILE` variables).
- optionally, the user is mapped to the SELinux user `staff_u` and given rights to execute commands as other user as required via `sudo`.
- the user's `/home`, `/tmp` and possibly `/var/tmp` are polyinstantiated via `/etc/security/namespace.conf`:

  ```
  /tmp       /tmp/.inst/tmp.inst-$USER-     tmpdir:create   root
  /var/tmp   /tmp/.inst/var-tmp.inst-$USER- tmpdir:create   root
  $HOME      $HOME/$USER.inst/              tmpdir:create   root
  ```

  Also, `/etc/security/namespace.init` makes all skeletal files readonly for the user and owned by `root`.

This way you can choose whether `$USER` can execute any command on his/her own behalf (via a link in the private `~/bin` directory, provisioned via `/etc/skel`, as explained above), on behalf of other user (via `sudo`) or none at all.

With regards to "access to a set of files", you don't specify whether it's read-only or read-write access.

In any case, this can be set up through `sudo` rules.
I would implement rules to grant read-only access to files via `rview` and read-write via `rvim`, the latter normally being configured using the `editor` directive in your `sudoers` file:

```
Defaults editor=/usr/bin/rvim
```

So users can `sudoedit` allowed files.

This solution can be fairly easily implemented using your configuration management tool of choice.

New commands can be added to the private `~/bin` directory very quickly (since they are just symlinks managed from the namespacing logic).
New `sudo` rules can also be managed the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the response (and sorry it took me so long to reply)! I'll pass this along to my sysadmin team and see what we can do.